# FullCalendar: How to save/send modified events to DB or service on eventDrop (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a FullCalendar object integrated into my node.js solution, and it accepts events via json coming from a REST service fronting a database.

How can I save the updated events back to the central database once they are dragged to a new time slot (on eventDrop)?

global.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'); 
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        defaultView: "timeGridWeek",
        height: "auto",
        slotDuration: "00:60:00",
        navLinks: true,
        events: '/classes/jsonlist',
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'interaction' ],
        editable: true,
        eventDrop: function(info) {
          var new_event_start_time = info.event.start.toLocaleTimeString();
          if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to move it to "+new_event_start_time+" ?")) {
            info.revert();
          };
//        Update database record for the event
//
        var xhr = $.ajax({
          url: "/classes/jsonset",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify( { 'id': info.event.id, 'url': info.event.url, 'title': info.event.title,'new_start': info.event.start } ),
          timeout: 5000
        }).done(function( msg ){
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });           

        }
      }
    );
  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: You need to make an AJAX request to the server and send the event data in the request

Comment: @ADyson Okay, I was able to do that, except event id always gets sent as an empty string (title, url, start etc are populated with correct new values). Any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing the code you used, the external events or their data, it's impossible to be sure what the issue could be. You'd have to show all that if you need help with it

Comment: @ADyson see the code added above. On a simple event move to another time slot, here is the type of payload it produces: { id: '',
  url: '/classes/5db1c5b18c49732f54c41ecb',
  title: 'Advanced Logic',
  new_start: '2019-10-25T17:00:00.000Z' }

Comment: ok. But did your events have an ID to begin with? That's why I asked you to share the data of the original external events coming from the server

Comment: If your events already have IDs then there should be no problem. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExxbvXO - check the console log if you drag the Sales or Marketing meetings (which have IDs) versus the Production meeting (which doesn't have an ID)